# Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT using Spring Rest Template

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am using the Rest Template to invoke a third party Restful API. but I am getting the "Can not serialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT" Below is the code:

```
xml file:

<!-- RESTful interaction -->
<bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
</bean>
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

**java code:**

response= restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
```

The url is valid URL in the restTemplate.getForObject() method. I verified it putting the same URL in the browser and it produces the valid JSON object.

Below is the error I am getting:

> [5/9/13 16:25:56:352 CDT] 00000028 SystemErr     R
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String
>   out of START_OBJECT token  at [Source:
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@3dd83dd8;
>   line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize
>   instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token  at [Source:
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@3dd83dd8;
>   line: 1, column: 1]

What am I doing Wrong?

Comment: What does the JSON response from the rest service look like?

Comment: It is a valid JSON file, but I wanted to capture that JSON response as a String.

Comment: What does it look like? Can you post the JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was that I was only using one message converter. After removing the

```
<property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
```

This code from the bean declaration it started working. Because now RestTemplate started using it's own message converters. Now the code looks like this:

```
<!-- RESTful interaction -->
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate" />
```

Comment: Specifically, I added a string converter: 
converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());